# Excluding items from a crawl based on properties

Tags: 2013, 2007, enterprise-search, crawling, crawl-rules

We have a 2013 farm that is crawling a 2007 content source with a lot of outdated content in it. We'd really like to exclude items from the crawl based on their last modified date, but we're having trouble figuring out the best way to do it. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to do it, preferably keeping the SP object model intact?

The best way we've come up with is running a PS script to get the modified dates and using that to programmatically create/update crawl rules that exclude the old items. It seems like a messy solution to what should be an easy problem, but I don't know where else to go with it at this point.

**Edit:** Per the title of the question, answers can address how to crawl based on *any* property, not just LastModifiedDate, because that would be useful for more than just my specific situation.

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple options with different complexity:

1. Use CEWS or the advanced version, see: (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/richard_dizeregas_blog/archive/2013/06/19/advanced-content-enrichment-in-sharepoint-2013-search.aspx)
2. Create a custom connector
3. Use your solution to first get the items url based on any property - that can be very generic - and then exclude them with a crawl rule.

I think 3. has the least effort, 2. would be the most flexible solution and 1. would slow down your crawl most likely.

In other words: I would not exclude the items during crawl because of the increased maintenance, efforts and risks :)